# how to send a post request with body using SwiftHTTP swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to make a post request with a body in swift using swiftHTTP

My JSON body looks as follows

```
 {
  "EmailId":"abc@gmail.com",
  "UserSecurityQuestions": [
  {
  "Id": 1,
  "SecurityQuestions": "What is your favourate pet name",
  "Answer":"candy"
  },
  {
  "Id": 2,
  "SecurityQuestions": "What was your favorite place to visit as a   child?",
  "Answer":"paris"
  },

  {
  "Id": 8,
  "SecurityQuestions": "What is your favorite movie?",
  "Answer":"parisin"
  }
  ]
 }
```

I am trying to call it in the following way

```
    let datasecqArray = [ ["Id" : self.secques1,"SecurityQuestions" :    SecurityQuestionOneTextField.text!, "Answer" :AnswerOneTextField.text!],["Id" : self.secques2,"SecurityQuestions" : SecurityQuestionTwoTextField.text!, "Answer" :AnswerTwoTextField.text!],["Id" : self.secques3,"SecurityQuestions" : SecurityQuestionThreeTextField.text!, "Answer" : AnswerThreeTextField.text!] ]

    let useremail = PHCConstant.defaults.value(forKey: "emailForUser") as! String
    let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: datasecqArray, options: [])
    let string = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let parDic = ["EmailId":useremail,"UserSecurityQuestions": string! as Any] as [String:Any]
```

I am posting the parDic constant as a param in the post. On printing the parDic i am getting the output as

```
  [
   "EmailId":"abc@gmail.com",
   "UserSecurityQuestions": [
   {
   "Id": 1,
   "SecurityQuestions": "What is your favourate pet name",
    "Answer":"candy"
   },
  {
  "Id": 2,
  "SecurityQuestions": "What was your favorite place to visit as a      child?",
  "Answer":"paris"
  },

 {
 "Id": 8,
 "SecurityQuestions": "What is your favorite movie?",
 "Answer":"parisin"
 }
]
]
```

how to get the output as presented in the JSON body instead as above which is array within an array.. please help me and apologies for my grammar

Comment: Both the output are same.

Comment: but my posting to the serve wasn't successful.. I am getting server error message

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: @NiravD on success i will be receiving a success message on failure i will be receiving server error message as questions hasn't been created successfully thats the error i am receeving

Comment: Instead of passing array as string pass it as array with parDic like this way `let parDic = ["EmailId":useremail,"UserSecurityQuestions": datasecqArray] as [String:Any]`

Comment: Is it works after changing the `parDic` ?

Comment: i won't be getting the desire output format, the output is as follows                                        ["EmailId": "rival510@gmail.com", "UserSecurityQuestions": [["Answer": "hyd", "SecurityQuestions": "What was your favorite place to visit as a child?", "Id": 2], ["Answer": "Mike", "SecurityQuestions": "Who is your favorite actor, musician, or artist?", "Id": 3], ["Answer": "hyd", "SecurityQuestions": "In what city were you born?", "Id": 5]]]

Comment: What do you mean by that? Have you tried making post request? The console log is correct, in Swift it will show you `[:]` for dictionary not the `{}` one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138637/discussion-between-ashwin-and-nirav-d).